# The closer the x/y the more x/y velocity

Tags: javascript, velocity, distance

I am writing a fairly simple script in JavaScript using the canvas. It draws a central node which pulls all of the surrounding nodes towards it. This works great, however I need each node to repel each other.

I am going to do this by increasing each nodes velocity away from each other so eventually they should level out and end up looking something like a flower. It needs to be enough force to stop them from hitting each other or sinking into the center node without flying off into the distance.

I just can not work out how I can have a higher number the closer they get.

So if two nodes where 10px away from each other it would add 5 in force to one of their x velocities. But if they where 1000px away from each other then it would add almost nothing to the force of one of the nodes.

Does anyone know of a mathematical equation I can use to work this kind of thing out, or maybe a nudge in the right direction?

**TL;DR:** Depending on how close two x values are, I need to increment the x velocity of one node so they move apart but eventually level out. It is just the maths I can not crack, I have pretty much all of the JavaScript done, including the implementation of velocity.

Thanks, and sorry it is a bit wordy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need an inverse (or inverse square) relationship:

```
var increment = k / distance;
```

or:

```
var increment = k / (distance * distance);
```

You can determine `k` based on the actual values you want, for example, in the first case, if you wanted an increment of 5 for a distance of 10, you would set `k = increment * distance = 50`.

Comment: So I assume if `k` was extremely high then they would be able to get closer with less force. Say around the 190 mark? They all seem to have way too much force at the moment and flying all over the place. If you have a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wolfy87/KAktJ/51/) and search for this comment. `// Calculate velocities`. Any pointers. I know I am completely wrong, I am just not sure where.

Comment: Oh sorry, `k = increment * distance` >_> I am trying to test it but jsFiddle is running *very* slow.

Comment: @Wolfy87: That's a nice simulation you've got there. :)

Comment: Yeah, it looks quite cool mostly by accident ^^ I am just trying to get them to settle, but I cant quite get it right :|

Comment: @casablanca I can see that I am now in the right direction, I still can not get it right though. For instance, when calculating k, what would I use as an increment? They are still flying about :S

Comment: @casablanca Oh got close using [this page](http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-squarelaw.htm). They just seem to shoot off when they hit the same location as each other.

Answer (score 2):

Look into the equations governing electrical point charges, have the velocity be based on the "force" each "charge" would feel based on its proximity.